# Не перерисовывается CheckBox в DataGridView после изменения значения ячейки

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Пишу в обработчике события (например на кнопке).

```
MyGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = !(bool)MyGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value
Console.WriteLine(MyGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```

При этом в консоль исправно пишутся чередующиеся Правда и Ложь, но вот сам чекбокс на форме остается неизменным. Как заставить отрисовываться галку в соответствии со значением?

Изначально создавалась таблица DataTable со столбцом типа bool, после чего передалась в качестве источнику для DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что фокус установлен на ячейке, значение которой изменяется. Редактор ячейки не обновляет значение, т.к. оно в данный момент вводится пользователем.

Чтобы обновить редактор текущей ячейки принудительно, воспользуйтесь методом [`DataGridView.RefreshEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.refreshedit(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
MyGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = !(bool)MyGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value
MyGridView.RefreshEdit();
```

Comment: Нет, вы правы. Я не подумал об этом, т.к. в таблице была только одна строка и не было возможности заметить, что остальные строки изменяются. Теперь поправил - работает. В цикле нужно выделить было столбец и так опростоволосился=)

Comment: Обращу внимание, что метод `Refresh` перерисовывает контрол, но никак не связан с привязкой данных. Т. е. в данном случае неприменим.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за замечание! Предположил, что могла быть проблема в отображении. Эта часть ответа не пригодилась автору вопроса, убрал ее, чтобы никого не сбить с толку.